# How to create web3.js which is used in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'd like to know how to create https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/jsre/deps/web3.js file automatically.
It seems like bundled by some tools but I cannot find any mention or docs in the geth repo.
Is there anyone who knows how to create bundled web3.js automatically embeded in geth?
Thanks in advance for all your answers

FYI.

- I already knows how web3 works and I used it several times because Im a developer.
- Just wanna know how they bundled that web3 library and maintain that bundled file. (e.g. bundle web3 library using gulp, etc...)

Comment: It is just a minified version of web3 v0.20.1. I think the hardest thing to upgrade it is generating a version that can run inside [goja](https://github.com/dop251/goja) the javascript interpreter used by go-ethereum.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your comment. But how to create that minified version of that version of web3? What tool would they use..?

Comment: Check the repo at that version https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/ it has a command to build the minified file.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your detailed comment. It was really helpful.
One more thing. How did you know that Geth use specified version v0.20.1?
(Updated.)
I knew that.. there is a specified version in the web3.js :)

Comment: @Ismael But the actual build command seems different.
I generated file using build command and compared them and there were some differences.

Comment: I'd check if there's a branch for the exact version v0.20.1, I'd also check the npm dependencies. I don't know if at that time web3 builds were reproducible.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your help. Appreciate about it.